# Growth curves in R with standard deviation

Tags: ggplot2, plot, line, anova, errorbar

I am trying to plot my data (replicate results for each strain) and i want only one line graph for each strain, this means averaged results of replicates for each strain with points along the line with error bars (error between replicate data).

[image: lines unfortunately separate for each strain replicate]

If you click on the image above, it shows the plot i have so far, which displays WT and WT.1 as seperate lines and all other replicates. However, they are replicates of each strain (WT,DrsbR,DsigB) and i want them to appear as one line of mean results for each strain instead. I am using ggplot package- and melting data with reshape package, but cannot figure out how to make my replicates appear as one line together with error bars (standard deviation of mean results between replicates).
The image in black and white is something i am looking for in my graph- seperate line with points of replicate data plotted as a mean value.

[image: This image shows similiar plot i am looking for, each line representing 2 or 3 replicates with points along the line with errors of data tested at each time point]

```
library(reshape2)
melted<-melt(abs2)
print(abs2)
melted<-melt(abs2,id=1,measured=c("WT","WT.1","DsigB","DsigB.1","DrsbR","DrsbR.1"))
View(melted)
colnames(melted)<-c("Time","Strain","Values")
##line graph for melted data
melted$Time<-as.factor(melted$Time)
abs2line=ggplot(melted,aes(Time,Values))+geom_line(aes(colour=Strain,group=Strain))
abs2line+
  stat_summary(fun=mean,
               geom="point",
               aes(group=Time))+
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_boot,
               geom="errorbar",
               width=.2)+
  xlab("Time")+
  ylab("OD600")+
  theme_classic()+
  labs(title="Growth Curve of Mutant Strains")
summary(melted)
print(melted)
```

Comment: it would be easier when you include some data we can work with. Nevertheless, I think you only need to specify the color inside `aes` of the `stat_summary`s.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The main struggle is to get the Strains I listed in the legend (figure 1) to become one line of average data and not separate lines so i can then display error bars clearly for each strain averages.. Color function did not change anythinh except the colour of the points for me.

Comment: Perhaps i need to group the replicates Wt and Wt.1 and calculate the means and SD then plot it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to take your melted data frame and `separate` out the "variable" column into "species" and "strain" using the `separate()` function from `tidyr`.  I don't have your dataset -- it is appreciated if you are able to share your dataset via `dput(your.data.frame)` for future questions -- so I made a dummy dataset that's similar to yours.  Here we have two "species" (red and blue) and two "strains" for each species.

```
df <- data.frame(
    time = seq(0, 40, by=10),
    blue = c(0:4),
    blue.1 = c(0, 1.1, 1.9, 3.1, 4.1),
    red = seq(0, 8, by=2),
    red.1 = c(0, 2.1, 4.2, 5.5, 8.2)
)

df.melt <- melt(df,
    id.vars = 'time',
    measure.vars = c('blue', 'blue.1', 'red', 'red.1'))
```

We can then use `tidyr::separate()` to separate the resulting "variable" column into a "species" column and a "strain" column.  Luckily, your data contains a "." which can be a handy character to use for the separation:

```
df.melt.mod <- df.melt %>%
    separate(col=variable, into=c('species', 'strain'), sep='\\.')
```

*Note: The above code will give you a warning related to the point that "blue" and "red" do not have the "." character, thereby giving you NA for the "strain" column.  We don't care here, because we're not using that column for anything here.  In your own dataset, you can similarly not care too much.*

Then, you can actually just use `stat_summary()` for all geoms... modify as you see fit for your own visual and thematic preference.  Note that order matters for layering, so I plot `geom_line` first, then `geom_point`, then `geom_errorbar`.  Also note that you can assign the `group=species` aesthetic in the base `ggplot()` call and that mapping applies to all `geoms` unless overwritten.

```
ggplot(df.melt.mod, aes(x=time, y=value, group=species)) +
    stat_summary(
        fun = mean,
        geom='line',
        aes(color=species)) +
    stat_summary(
        fun=mean,
        geom='point') +
    stat_summary(
        fun.data=mean_cl_boot,
        geom='errorbar',
        width=0.5) +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: That worked, thank you. But is there any way of find out the values of SD or mean without using excel for my individual points of error?

Comment: Absolutely!  Best to present in a data.frame.  I would use `group_by()` and `summarize()` from `dplyr`.  Example with the dataset above: `df.melt.mod %>% group_by(species, time) %>% summarize(mean.val=mean(value), sd.val=sd(value))`.  That gives you a tibble - I like to store and represent `as.data.frame`, but that's your preference.  Leaving out "time" summarizes only by species over all timepoints.  Leaving out "species" summarizes by timepoints over all species... etc etc.

Comment: If you want to display that info on your plot (via a `text` geom, for example), just save the output from that in a data frame and use that data for a `geom_text` call.  You have to adjust some of the aesthetics to work, but if you save the output of the code above into `add.info`, you can add this to the plot call I did in the answer to get nice text labels of standard deviation at each point: `geom_text(data=add.info, aes(y=mean.value, 
label=paste0('sd=',round(sd.value, 2))), nudge_x=-1.2, nudge_y=0.3, size=3)`